# Obtener lista de comentarios mediante una consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, php5

En mi base de datos general tengo algunas bases de datos:

- `information schema`
- `performance schema`
- `mysql`
- `phpadmin`
- `wordpress`
- `test`

La base que utilizo es `test`, en el interior tengo mi tabla `commenti` que contiene *3 campos* los cuales son:

- `nome varchar(15)`
- `commento varchar (255)`
- `fecha date`

En mi página principal tengo un una caja de texto y una caja de comentarios, esto me sirve como sistema de comentarios. Si alguien quiere dejar un comentario es suficiente poner el nombre y el comentario. Cuando este evento ocurre, los datos viajan por el metodo `get` y luego los datos, se almacenan en mi tabla  `commenti`.

Hasta este punto no hay ningún problema con mi siguiente código:

```
<form method="get" action="conexion.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="commento"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
mysql_select_db('test', $conexion) or die (mysql_error());

$name = $_GET['name'];
$commento = $_GET['commento'];
$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO commenti (nome, commento, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$commento', '$fecha')" ;
mysql_query($sql);

echo $name;
echo $commento;
```

Con esto obtengo el nombre, el comentario y la fecha mostrada en la página.

Sin embargo lo que quiero hacer es poder visualizar todos los comentarios en mi página principal. Para este proposito he añadido un bucle `while` que va recuperando los datos de mi tabla `commenti`, sin embargo hay un error que no logro entender.

```
<form method="get" action="conexion.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="commento"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
mysql_select_db('test', $conexion);

$query = "SELECT * FROM commenti";
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $fila['nome'];
    echo $fila['commento'];
    echo $fila['fecha'];
}
?>
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in F:\xamp\htdocs\local\basico\demo.php on line 12

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` espera como parámetro el resultado de `mysql_query` y no una cadena ,  como consejo **dejar de emplear la extensión `mysql` , en su lugar emplear `mysqli` o `PDO`** , importante leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Comment: disculpa pero todo mi proyecto esta hecho con mysql, lo cambiare en mi proximo proyecto, sin embargo no entendi tu respuesta, el resultado de query es un resource y por lo tanto se puede acceder solo por arrays, si no es asi aclarame bien las ideas, no soy experto en servidores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que se observa en su código `PHP` y por lo cuál muestra el error es que la función [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) espera un resource *(resultado)* de [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) y usted le envía una cadena simplemente.

Su código sería algo así.

```
<?php
  $conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
  mysql_select_db('test', $conexion);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM commenti";
  $resultado = mysql_query($query);/* Línea que falta*/
   while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     echo $fila['nome'];
     echo $fila['commento'];
     echo $fila['fecha'];
   }
?>
```

Como recomendación dejar de utilizar *mysql* emplear *Mysqli* o *PDO* para de alguna manera evitar [La Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

Te falto ejecutrar la query, remplaza

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM commenti";
```

por

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenti");
```